# django template filter chaning - get last element of last element

Tags: django, django-templates

So I'm throwing together a basic forum as an example and I want to display in the template the date (and I suppose username) of the last post.

So my first thought was something like this:

```
topics|last.post_set.all|last.created
```

Django does not like this and gives me a TemplateSyntaxError:

"Could not parse some characters: topics|last|.post_set.all||last.created".

So I guess I can't chain filters and methods and so like this.

I think I might be on the wrong track here but I'm not sure what else I can do from the template.

Any suggestions other than the obvious "do it in the view"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want last item, according to some date, define [`Meta.get_latest_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) in both models and use

```
topics.latest.post_set.latest.created
```

Comment: Nice, simple and djangoy. Thanks.